# How to stop a timer in a component when using RouteReuseStrategy?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an Angular 8 application and am making use of route reuse with a RouteReuseStrategy.  I would like to have a polling refresh in one component, so I have implemented an interval subscription.  In my example, this outputs the current time to the console every second.

```
export class GridComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private gridTimer: Subscription;

  constructor() {
    console.log('setting refresh timer');
    this.gridTimer = interval(1000).subscribe(() => {this.timerTick()});

  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    console.log('unsubscribe grid timer');
    this.gridTimer.unsubscribe();
  }

  timerTick(){
    let date = new Date();
    console.log('timer tick: ' + date.toTimeString());
  }
}
```

When I turn off my RouteReuseStrategy, the component is successfully destroyed and I can unsubscribe my timer.  However the component is not destroyed if route reuse is implemented.

Here is a plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/bVuSwXwKfy86mkAHtS48?p=preview

src/gridWithTimer.ts displays a grid and has a timer.  When viewing the detail of a person, the timer will unsubscribe.

In src/app.ts, comment out line 28 and comment in line 29 to turn route reuse on.  View the detail of a person and the timer continues to tick.

(Please turn the console on to see debug messages)

I would like to use route reuse to cache the grid results, but I would also like the ability to stop the timer when the user is viewing the details component (or any other component).  I assume I'm hooking into the wrong part of the component lifecycle?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should send signal from CustomReuseStrategy, i.e. by RxJS.Subject,

in component use

```
interval(1000)
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(subjectFromStartegy),
    repeat() //optional
  )
  .subscribe(() => {this.timerTick()})
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/repeat.html

Comment: Please could you give me some information on where the subjectFromStrategy is set?  How does the component get this information?  Thanks

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/acIs1WZkKVkN99iJgCOw?p=preview, GridComponent and CustomReuseStrategy, maybe it's not the best practice

Comment: Thanks for the update.  The timer seems to still tick when viewing the details, and stops when returning to the grid.  I was hoping that the timer would stop when viewing the details (and all other pages), and restart when viewing the grid.  But I can see the direction you are heading